# How to use go-сmp to compare such structs?

Tags: go, go-cmp

I have the following simplified set of structs

```
type S0 struct {
  UUID uuid.UUID
  F00  int
  F01  int
}

type S1 struct {
  S0
  F10 int
  F11 int 
}

type S2 struct {
  S0
  F20 int
}

<...>

type SN struct {
  S0
  FN0 int
  <...>
  FNM int
}
```

A struct `S0` is equal to another struct `S0` if all their fields(`UUID`, `F0i`) are equal. The struct `Sk (k=1..N)` is equal to the struct `Sk`, if their parts `Sk.S0` are equal, even if all their fields `Fki` are not equal. But if their parts `Sk.S0` are not equal, then structs will still be equal, if all their fields `Fki` are equal. Struct `S0` is equal to any other struct `Sk` if `Sk.S0 == S0`. The struct `Si` is never equal to the struct `Sj (i != j)`, even if `Si.S0 == Sj.S0`(In theory, this is generally unrealistic in current architecture, but just in case). All structs implement a common interface `I`.
I want to write the following equality function using go-cmp.

```
func EqualI(i1 I, i2 I) bool
```

I wrote the following comparison functions for each struct, which looks about the same, but how to combine them into one function `EqualI` and not get an error 'ambiguous set of applicable options'?

```
func EqualS0(s0_a S0, s0_b S0) bool {
  return cmp.Equal(s0_a, s0_b)
}

func EqualS1(s1_a S1, s1_b S1) bool {
  if EqualS0(s1_a.S0, s1_b.S0) {
    return true
  }

  return cmp.Equal(s1_a, s1_b, cmpopts.IgnoreFields(S1{}, "S0.UUID", "S0.F00", "S0.F01"))
}
```

Comment: Hi JohnnyIpcom, How about using map[string]interface{} instead of struct ?

Answer (score 0):

Good Day!

Here is the sample code using the map[string]interface. You can also see it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/DcvGDwICnIw).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    
    one := map[string]interface{} {
        "uuid":"123-456-789",
        "F00":0,
        "F01":1,
        "F10":3,
    }
    
    other := map[string]interface{} {
        "uuid":"987-654-321",
        "F00": 2,
        "F01": 3,
        "F10": 3,
    }
    
    fmt.Println("Result of Full Comparison = ", compare(one, other))
    
    fmt.Println("Result of Part Comparison = ", compareIgnoreSome(one,other, []string{"uuid","F00","F01"}))
}

func compare(a map[string]interface{}, b map[string]interface{}) bool {

    for k1,v1 := range a{
        if v2,exists := b[k1]; !exists {
            return false
        } else {
        
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(v1, v2) {
                return false
            }
        }
        
    }
    return true
}




func compareIgnoreSome(a map[string]interface{}, b map[string]interface{}, some []string) bool {
    sort.Strings(some) 

    
    for k1,v1 := range a{
        if i := sort.SearchStrings(some, k1); i>=0 {            
            continue
        } 
        
        fmt.Println("target key= ", k1)
        if v2,exists := b[k1]; !exists {
            return false
        } else {
        
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(v1, v2) {
            
                fmt.Printf("Diff %v, %v\n", v1, v2)
                return false
            }
        }
        
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: You know, this might be a good idea. But in a slightly different version, it is still much more convenient to use structs in the rest of the code. But such a complex comparison is needed only in one place, before adding/retrieving these structs to the MongoDB storage in order to avoid duplicates. After all, you can store and restore structs from the repository in any form. I know there is a nice library mapstructure that allows you to convert struct to map. I've never used it, but it can help. Thank you, I did not think about this question from this side.

Comment: Okay, It's slightly different. I think,you would better use a mapstruct library.

Answer (score 0):

is better do not to use the `cmp` package for production, I [quote](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#pkg-overview):

> It is intended to only be used in tests, as performance is not a goal and it may **panic** if it cannot compare the values.

Suppose you have the following interface implemented by `S0`...`SN`:

```golang
type I interface {
    Foo()
}
```

You can write `EqualI` considering your requirements like follows

```golang
import "reflect"

func EqualI(i1 I, i2 I) bool {
    v1 := reflect.ValueOf(i1)
    v2 := reflect.ValueOf(i2)
    t1 := v1.Type()

    // if i1, i2 are not of the same type
    if t1 != v2.Type() {
        return false
    }

    // If i1,i2 are S0 structs
    if s00, ok := i1.(S0); ok {
        return reflect.DeepEqual(s00, i2.(S0))
    }

    // If i1,i2 are not S0 structs
    // then check for the SO field
    fieldS00 := v1.Field(0).Interface().(S0)
    fieldS01 := v2.Field(0).Interface().(S0)
    if reflect.DeepEqual(fieldS00, fieldS01) {
        return true
    }

    // in other case check the rest of fields
    for i := 1; i < t1.NumField(); i++ {
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(v1.Field(i).Interface(), v2.Field(i).Interface()) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

With the `reflect` package you can access a struct member at runtime.

### Notes

The order is very important for `K=1..N`, `SK` struct, every `SK` must have `S0` as the first field:

```golang
type SK struct {
  S0
  // your fields ...    
}
```

[image: GoLang Playground]